# Profile Name link is not showing of user , which is commented on Post

Tags: html, django, django-templates

show_more.html ( This is the template of the Post and see comments and add comments )

```
   <hr>
{% for comment in comments %}
  <div class="comment">
    <p class="info">
      {{ comment.created_at|naturaltime }}
      Commented by :-  <a href="{% url 'mains:show_profile' comment.commented_by.id %}"></a> # I think the problem is in this line. BUT i've tried everything.
        {{ topic.post_owner }}
    </p>
    {{ comment.comment_body|linebreaks }}
  </div>
{% empty %}
  <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried everything but nothing works, Please help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help.

Comment: please add the urls.py as well to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass **comment.commented_by.id** to kwarg of URL **'user_id'**

```
<a href="{% url 'mains:show_profile' user_id=comment.commented_by.id %}"> {{ comment.commented_by }} </a>
```

Comment: Sir, it is showing blank on after Commented by :-

It is not showing the name

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
comment.commented_by
```

instead of

```
comment.commented_by.id.
```